# Antlr4 float number

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to use ANTLR4 to parse input from user but having a hard time.

I want to get a list of numbers. Here is part of my grammar:

```
number
    : DEC 
    | FLOAT
    | HEX
    | BIN
    ;

FLOAT   : DIGIT? '.' DIGIT*;
DEC     : DIGIT+ ;
HEX     : '0' [xX] ([A-Fa-f] | DIGIT)+ ;
BIN     : '0' [bB] [01]+ ;

fragment ALPHA: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];

WS :    [ ,\t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

When input is `1 .2 3.2` then I get `1` `.2` `3.2`

But if I use `1.2.3` it incorrectly recognizes `1.2` `.3`

How can I change the grammar to fix this?

Comment: Can you add a formal description of what you actually want? How should the parser behave (actually the lexer in this case) for various input?

Comment: Why is it incorrect that the input `"1.2.3"` creates the tokens `1.2` and `.3`? There is probably no parser rule that accepts 2 successive `FLOAT` tokens, resulting in a semantic error for that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FLOAT` rule seems wrong. I have updated `number` and `FLOAT` definitions. Below code works only single numbers.

```
number
    : (FLOAT | DEC | HEX | BIN) EOF
    ;

FLOAT   : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
        | '.' DIGIT+
        ;
DEC     : DIGIT+;
HEX     : '0' [xX] ([A-Fa-f] | DIGIT)+ ;
BIN     : '0' [bB] [01]+ ;

fragment ALPHA: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];

WS :    [ ,\t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

In most complex grammars, there are other tokens like `signs`, `parenthesis`.. etc. So we can easily handle separate tokens with `space` skipping. However, your grammar has only numbers and I can not separate tokens with skipping spaces. So, I discarded the whitespace skip definition. Below code handle many numbers and fails if the word is like `1.2.3`. You should test with `numbers` and don't process `WS` tokens.

```
numbers
    : WS? number (WS number)* WS? EOF;

number
    : (FLOAT | DEC | HEX | BIN)
    ;

FLOAT   : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
        | '.' DIGIT+
        ;
DEC     : DIGIT+;
HEX     : '0' [xX] ([A-Fa-f] | DIGIT)+ ;
BIN     : '0' [bB] [01]+ ;

fragment ALPHA: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];

WS :    [ ,\t\r\n]+;
```

Comment: Your `FLOAT` rule also accepts a single dot (`.`): that can't be right. Besides that, the OP didn't explain what they wanted the input `1.2.3` to be tokenised as, so we can't know what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, I realized after posted it. I fixed it, could you check?

Comment: My second remark still stands: we (you included) can't know what the OP wants: they didn't explain that.

Comment: I forced the grammar to failed when entered any word like `1.2.3`.

Comment: Chances are that the parser rules the OP didn't share (which I'm sure there are) already rejected two successive `FLOAT` tokens. You also changed the `WS` to become a token on it's own, resulting in all other parser rules needing to account for that.